# Второе я

Tags: орфография

"Мое второе я берет верх" — как правильно писать Я? С большой буквы, в кавычках или так, как написано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причин для заглавной я тут не вижу никаких.
В отношении кавычек - вопрос спорный. Но если закавычивать, то весь оборот: "второе я". Впрочем, я бы и этого не стал делать, оборот прочно вошёл в язык.

[gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru) подтверждает:

*Вопрос № 263363  

здравствуйте, ув. справочная служба!

подскажите, пожалуйста, стоит ли брать в кавычки "я" в выражении: это мое второе я???
спасибо за ответ*
lighty

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Можно в этом случае обойтись без кавычек.